# How to make images searchable via Ctrl+F

Tags: html, css

I have a page with a large products table. Each product is represented by an image.

I would like to make each product name searchable using the browser's "search in page" feature. When searching for a product name, the user should end up at the respective image.

I can not add a product name that is visible as text (the name is already very prominently on each image) but can add text elements that are not visible.

Is there a robust way to do this?

Comment: So like, make the CTRL + F use the `alt` attribute?

Comment: @4castle essentially, yes - although I'm open to (reliable) shenanigans with HTML text and CSS.

Comment: I don't think there really is a way to do this, a better solution would be to have something like a search box on your page that searches using the `alt` attribute of images. You could do this with Javascript.

Comment: does putting the text underneath (as in, z-index, not just putting the text below) the image let it be searched?

Comment: See [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516248/browser-ctrl-f-find-and-non-visible-text). I think it's impossible, sadly, to change a browser feature like that.

Answer (score 3):

How about hiding some text behind the image? Something like this.

```
<div class="image-block">
   <div class="img-description">Some text.</div>
   <img>
</div>

.image-block {
   position: relative;
}

.img-description {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.image-block img {
  position: relative;
}
```

Basically, this will put the image over the `img-description` element, so you can still search and find it.

Comment: I tried this out, and I can verify that it works. Very creative! My idea was to use text that was very very small (like 1px). It worked also.

Answer (score 1):

Using `z-index`, you can hide the text behind the image. This lets it be searched for with Chrome, Safari and Firefox (unfortunately can't test in IE).

```
<html>
<body>
<style>
.product-image {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
img.product {
    position:absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
div.product {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
}
</style>

<table>
<tr><td><div class="product-image"><img src="product-image.png" class="product"></img><div class="product">name 1</div></div></td></tr>
<tr><td><div class="product-image"><img src="product-image.png" class="product"></img><div class="product">something else...</div></div></td></tr>
<table>
</body>
</html>
```

It works well in FF & Chrome, however in Safari it pulls the text out from behind the image, which your users may find jarring.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions here have the problem that the user can't tell they've found something, since the text they're searching for is hidden behind the image.  If there's 12 images on screen, it's not obvious which one has matched their search.

I do something similar, but I just have transparent text above the image.  `<p style="color:transparent">My product title</p>`.

That way when the browser scrolls to the right region, the user can also see a blue selection growing around the text as they type it.

(In Chrome at least, the "transparent" text becomes visible once it's selected)